# Grafana synchronisation between two servers

Tags: bash, shell, grafana, grafana-api

i'm making a shell script to synchronize two instance of grafana but i always got the error *{"message":"folder title cannot be empty"}./dir_import.sh: line 25: -d: command not found*

but the title is not empty and i dont know wht ?

here is the code i try

```
for dir in ${TEMP_DIR}/folder.*.json; do
        name=$(jq -r .title "${dir}")
        echo "Uploading ${name} to Grafana"
        dir_json=$(jq '.| {uid: .uid, title: .title}' ${dir})
        curl -sSH "Authorization: Bearer $DEST_GRAFANA_API_KEY" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -X POST "${DEST_GRAFANA_ENDPOINT}/api/folders/" \
                -d @"${dir_json}"
    echo
done
```

Comment: Have you verified that `dir_json` contains what you expect? Please include example contents in the question.

Comment: Do you know what is a meaning of `@` in your `-d` parameter?

Comment: Yes, my json look like this : _{ "uid": "_JIiMx2mk", "title": "Autre" }_